# Finding Text within a nested list

Tags: jquery

i have a list that's dynamically generated. What i'm trying to do is show only the nested list of the page the person is on. How i think i can do that is by default i will hide all the nested items of this list, giving me only the first level of the (ul). What I want to do next is find in the nested list the name of the page (the name of the page will always be in the navigation) and when i find it, i want to show all of the found (li) neseted (ul)'s and parent (ul). Currently i got it so it only shows me the first level so my lists looks like this

```
Stone Mosaics
Glass Mosaics
Medallions & Murals
Etched Stone
```

If i'm on the basket weave page, i need it to look like this:

```
Stone Mosaics
  Basketweave
    one
    two
    three
  Blanch
  Chex
Glass Mosaics
Medallions & Murals
Etched Stone
```

So again, "find" Basketweave and show it and it's parent and it's children (1 level down). I hope this makes sense. Here's the code of the list:

```
<div id="subNav">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="/stone-mosaics?nav=collections">Stone Mosaics</a>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="/basketweave?nav=collections">Basketweave</a> </li>
        <ul>
          <li>one</li>
          <li>two</li>
          <li>three</li>
        </ul>
        <li> <a href="/blanch?nav=collections">Blanch</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/chex?nav=collections">Chex</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="/glass_mosaics?nav=collections">Glass Mosaics</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="/medallions_and_murals?nav=collections">Medallions &amp; Murals</a>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="/cucina?nav=collections">Cucina</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/glow?nav=collections">Glow</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/Louvre?nav=collections">Louvre</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/pools?nav=collections">Pools</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/Tapeti?nav=collections">Tapeti</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="/etched_stone?nav=collections">Etched Stone</a>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="/Barroque?nav=collections">Barroque</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/Bordo-Antico?nav=collections">Bordo Antico</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Are you looking to add additional functionality after this step, like expanding and collapsing the nodes? If so, you might want to use a tree implementation like [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/)? That provides an easy way to specify the nodes that need to be visible.

Comment: i'm actually not. i was able to figure out how to do it so that the subnav is shown $("#subNav li:contains('Basketweave')").parents('ul').show();, but i'm still trying to figure out how to do the children.

Comment: thanks for everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot alter the html or css here is a jquery solution:

```
$(document).ready()function(){
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;

    //remove the '/' then remove '?' and everything after it
    var fixpath = pathname.replace('/','').replace(/\?.+/,'');

    //in the case of url with two words, remove '-' and test with first word
    fixpath = fixpath.replace(/-.+/,'');

    //or remove everything after '_'
    fixpath = fixpath.replace(/_.+/,'');

    function capitaliseFirstLetter(string){
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }

    fixpath = capitaliseFirstLetter(fixpath);

    $('#subNav li:contains(' + fixpath + ')').parents('ul').show();
    $('#subNav li:contains(' + fixpath + ')').children('ul').show();
}
```

`contains()` is case sensitive so 'basketweave' would not be found but 'Basketweave' would. Found a function that will capitalize first letter to find a match.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/hKx8A/8/

Comment: Unfortunately i don't really have flexibility here. Seems to be somewhat working. The only thing is It's not showing the nested ul under Medallions & Murals, that doesn't work.

Comment: so the html is unchangeable and you can't use css is what you are saying?

Comment: Ok I updated my answer to be only jquery, there is still a problem that I'm tryin to work out though.

Comment: added a capitalize first letter function

Comment: fixed problem with multiple word urls

Comment: It's not a path i'm trying to match. The page that the person is on has a pageName variable (out of my control). The subNav has the same pageName in it as the li text. I cannot modify the text in the subNav. So i have to match pageName=subNav.pageName. Right now the problem i'm having is with the Medallions page, i'm thinking it's cause of the ampersand.

Comment: So what will the url read when a user is on that page? would it not be `http://www.yoursite.com/basketweave?nav=collections`? That is what this function does it reads the url as '/basketweave?nav=collections' and fixes it to match the `<li>` that contains that word.

Comment: $("#subNav li:contains('Basketweave')").parents('ul').show(); will search out the first instance it comes across in the subNav, in this case it would be <li> <a href="/basketweave?nav=collections">Basketweave</a></li>, which is the text contained within the Anchor.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is with that. Does the jsfiddle work the way you want?

Comment: it doesn't work the same way as the site does for some reason. On the site, using basketweave as the example, it show's the parent and the children, but on jsfiddle, using the same code, it does not. http://jsfiddle.net/grem28/4psQu/

Comment: In your fiddle you have a mistake. The `<ul>` is not nested inside the `<li>` so the `children()` can't get it. look at the fiddle I provided to see the correct way to right the html there.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, not in the actual code. Unfortunately, the code you provided in the fiddle is dealing with the url of the <li>. I can't rely on that cause sometimes the url could be "page_one.html" and the pageName could be something entirely different "Our Services". Any other ideas as to why it's not working on the medallions section?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more information in your question. Like what you have working so far and your full html.

Comment: here's what i got. If you put in anything besides the "Medallions & Murials", it'll work: http://jsfiddle.net/grem28/VTLcG/

Comment: well, if you search just for "Medallions" it will work. Otherwise it is looking for "Medallions & Murals" but the actual text is this: "Medallions &amp; Murals".

Comment: I fixed it. Here's what i did:   var pName = '<%=pageName%>';

  $('#subNav ul ul').hide();
  $("#subNav li:contains('"+pName.replace('&amp;','&')+"')").parents('ul').show();
  $("#subNav li:contains('"+pName.replace('&amp;','&')+"')").children('ul').show();

Answer (score 0):

i usually handle the sub-nav visibillity per '.active' class.

```
#subNav > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#subNav > ul > li.active > ul {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

My first suggestion is, that you should add this class during the nav generation (in backend i guess?).

If you want to solve it using jQuery... u could do something like this:

```
var href            = window.location.pathname,
    pagename        = href.split('/')[1];

$('#subNav > ul > li > a[href*="'+pagename+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Unfortunately i don't really have flexibility here. Seems to be somewhat working. The only thing is It's not showing the nested ul under Medallions & Murals, that doesn't work.

Comment: It might be because of the difference in the text encryption.

in 'Stone Mosaics' the space is replaced by a dash (-)
by 'Medallions & Murals' its '_ and _'

Comment: It's not a path i'm trying to match. The page that the person is on has a pageName variable (out of my control). The subNav has the same pageName in it as the li text. I cannot modify the text in the subNav. So i have to match pageName=subNav.pageName.